# Determine all ideals of $ \ \large \frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[x]}{(x^3+x+2)} \ $

Tags: abstract-algebra

Determine all ideals of $ \ \large \frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[x]}{(x^3+x+2)} \ $.

**Answer:**

The polynomial  $ \ x^3+x+2 \ $ is not irreducible in $ \ \mathbb{Z}_3 \ $ .

So we have to now factorise $ \ x^3+x+2 \ $ in order to get ideals.

But I can't factorise the polynomials andcan not find the ideals .

**Please help me out.**

Comment: It's a third degree polynomial: if it has non-trivial factors, then it must have linear factors, so it must have roots. Check whether $0, 1$ or $2$ are roots of that polynomial, and you have your linear factor.

Comment: yes $ \ x=2 \ $ is a root. So $ \ (x-2) \ $ will be a linear factor.  But how to find the ideals?

Comment: One big part of finding ideals of a ring is often to find the ring itself. You know that $x^3+x+2 = (x+1)p(x)$ for some second-degree polynomial $p(x)\in \Bbb Z_3[x]$. Which second degree polynomial is that? Now use the Chinese remainder theorem to write your ring as a direct product of nicer rings. Then find the ideals.

Comment: Arthur, can you write answer for us with Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Right, no need for CRT here. How silly of me.

Answer (score 3):

The ideals of any quotient ring $A/I$ coresponds to the ideals of $A$ that contain $I$. The ideals of $\Bbb Z_3[x]$ that contain $(x^3+x+2)$ are $(x^3+x+2), (x-2),(x^2-x-1)$ and $(x^2-x-1, x-2) = \Bbb Z_3[x]$. Divide each of these out by $(x^3+x+2)$, and you have your four ideals.

As for the Chinese reminder theorem (which, as it turns out, was unnecessary here), it says that the canonical ring homomorphism
$$
\Bbb Z_3[x]/(x^3+x+2)\to \Bbb Z_3[x]/(x-2)\times \Bbb Z_3[x]/(x^2-x-1)
$$
is an isomorphism. The ring on the right is a product of two fields (the first with three elements, the second with $9$), which makes looking for ideals easy (they are $(0), ((1,0)), ((0,1))$ and the whole ring)

Comment: Is $ \ \frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[x]}{(x^3+x+2)} \ $ an Integral domain ?

Comment: @yourmath Look at the Chinese remainder theorem decomposition: $(1,0)\cdot(0,1) = (0,0)$, so there are zero divisors. Alternatively, $x-2$ and $x^2-x-1$ are both non-zero. What about their product.

Answer (score 3):

The ideals of $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}_3[x]}{(x^3+x+2)}$ correspond to the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ that contain $(x^3+x+2)$.

Since $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ is a PID, the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ that contain $(x^3+x+2)$ are the ideals generated by the factors of $x^3+x+2$.

We have $x^3+x+2= (x + 1) (x^2 + 2 x + 2)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$. These factors are irreducible. Therefore, we have four the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ that contain $(x^3+x+2)$:

- $(1)$
- $(x+1)$
- $(x^2 + 2 x + 2)$
- $(x^3+x+2)$